# react-native Example/Movies fetch crash "undefined is not an object" evaluating responseData.total?

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, undefined, fetch-api

I am learning react-native starting with Movies example:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/Movies

The Movies example works great on an iPad Air.  When executed on an iPhone 5C, the app quickly crashes in the fetch:

> undefined is not an object ( evaluating 'responseData.total' ) 
>   SearchScreen.js @ 136:0

```js
    fetch(this._urlForQueryAndPage(query, 1))
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .catch((error) => {
        LOADING[query] = false;
        resultsCache.dataForQuery[query] = undefined;

        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.getDataSource([]),
          isLoading: false,
        });
      })
      .then((responseData) => {
        LOADING[query] = false;
        /*  *** Crash originates on following line 136 *** */
        resultsCache.totalForQuery[query] = responseData.total;
        resultsCache.dataForQuery[query] = responseData.movies;
        resultsCache.nextPageNumberForQuery[query] = 2;

        if (this.state.filter !== query) {
          // do not update state if the query is stale
          return;
        }

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: this.getDataSource(responseData.movies),
        });
      })
      .done();
  },
```

Fetch is hard to understand. What is the problem with this fetch ?

My concern is that before I even attempt to run Movies on Android, it crashes on the second iOS device tested.  I am hoping this is a fetch coding issue that just did not reveal itself on the iPad for some unknown reason.

Comment: How can I make the fetch fail gracefully ???                                                           The reason the fetch fails is my iPhone is blocked from rottentomatoes.com by the websense filter.  My iPad is a company-owned-device and is not blocked.

Comment: Is the `.catch` not giving you any info? Have you tried logging out the error?

Comment: maybe this link may help you to understand how fetch works: https://davidwalsh.name/fetch. also it links to the explanation of javascript promise.